# TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to classify cat and dog with pytorch. So I downloaded dataset from Kaggle, and separate train/validate set. I changed the file name from 00001.jpg to cat.00001.jpg..

But when I try to use `enumerate(dataset)`, this error occurs:

My dataset code is:

```
class TrainImageFolder(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform=None):
        self.transform = transform
        self.path = path
        self.image = []
        self.label = []
        for i in os.listdir(self.path):
            self.image.append(i)
            if i.startswith("cat"):
                self.label.append(0)
            elif i.startswith("dog"):
                self.label.append(1)
        assert len(self.label) == len(self.image)

    def __len__(self):
        len(self.image)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        label = self.label[index]
        img = Image.open(self.image[index]).convert("RGB")
        if self.transform:
            img = self.transform(img)
        return img, label

train_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

train_dataset = TrainImageFolder('train', transform=train_transform)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

for i, (imgs, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader)):
    print(labels)
```

and error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ge971/PycharmProjects/myVGG16/dataset.py", line 148, in <module>
    for i, (imgs, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataloader)):
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1166, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 435, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 474, in _next_data
    index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 427, in _next_index
    return next(self._sampler_iter)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 227, in __iter__
    for idx in self.sampler:
  File "C:\Users\ge971\miniconda3\envs\torch17\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\sampler.py", line 67, in __iter__
    return iter(range(len(self.data_source)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you let me know how to fix the error?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the line in `dataset.py` referenced at the top of your traceback where you're calling `enumerate()`?

Comment: There's not enough detail to meaningfully answer this, but that error seems related to the `range` function (`range(None)` throws this error) so you may have to trace the error through. Check the contents of `train_dataloader`, then `enumerate(train_dataloader)` to find the smallest single step that causes the error to occur

Comment: Yes as @G.Anderson said trace your error. My thoughts are: check your folder path and name, remove the point in between cat and your old filename. Maybe you use an underscore.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error, you forgot to return the length of the data in **len** function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your `__len__` function isn't returning the length of the image array like you want because you're not using the `return` keyword.

It should work if you change it to look like:

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.image)
```

Comment: I had the same issue with a data generator in tensorflow/keras (or rather with a keras.utils.Sequence object) and this solved it for me (Kartikey Chhipa caught it first, but this is the more complete answer).